# Difference between thin vs skeletonize in scikit-image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, mathematical-morphology

I have read the documentation but yet can't clearly differentiate between the skeletonize output and the thining output if we performed thousands of iterations in thining.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of difference. Iterating a thinning until convergence is one way to compute the skeleton. `skeletonize` has two different algorithms implemented, and they are both different from thinning, though all three produce comparable results.

From [this page](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html) of the scikit documentation:

> Morphological thinning, implemented in the `thin` function, works on the same principle as skeletonize: remove pixels from the borders at each iteration until none can be removed without altering the connectivity. The different rules of removal can speed up skeletonization and result in different final skeletons.

There is also a `medial_axis` function that, again, works under a different principle to produce a similar result.